# Idapython: How to get the opcode bytes corresponding to an instruction?

Tags: idapython, idapro-sdk

[image: IDA screen shot]

How do I get the `8B 45 FC` corresponding to the  `mov     eax, [rbp+var_4]`
etc. via idapython?

I did not come up with a better solution than

1. Getting the instruction via `idautils.DecodeInstruction()`
2. Getting the instruction's size in bytes
3. Looping over all bytes of the instruction and fetching the content via `idc.Byte()`

Is there a better solution, e.g. an api call (which I did not find)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another solution:

```
ea = ScreenEA() # Or whatever you want
buf = idc.GetManyBytes(ea, ItemSize(ea))
```

Comment: Much better than my try. If there is really no particular api function, this may be the best solution.